# How to add a pincode for admin in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, project, admin, config

I have an admin page but i want to change it such that when the admin enters a pincode to access the admin window. I know it has something to do with the app.config file. But i don't know how to put a pincode as a oneway hash.

thanks for helping!

(This is what i have in my app.config standard)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
`<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />

</startup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a PIN code for admin like that in app.config file.

But if you wish you can validate the identity of a user by asking the user to enter a password and then check it with the details in DB or source file and verify if the password is same. Else you could prevent the transition to the admin page.